# How to build a (My)SQL table structure for a table containing multiple foreign keys pointing to same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and I would like to have a table `hand` which would contain a fixed amount of `card`s (let's say 3 for the example, but I actually need 8). And I need to store every of these `hand`s but without duplicating an existing `hand`.

By "duplicating", I mean to avoid having two records containing the same data, like hand(1,2,3) and hand(2,1,3).

I currently have this :

```
CREATE TABLE card
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE hand
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    card_1 int(11),
    card_2 int(11),
    card_3 int(11)
)

ALTER TABLE card ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
ALTER TABLE hand ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)

ALTER TABLE hand ADD FOREIGN KEY (card_1) REFERENCES (card.id)
ALTER TABLE hand ADD FOREIGN KEY (card_2) REFERENCES (card.id)
ALTER TABLE hand ADD FOREIGN KEY (card_3) REFERENCES (card.id)
```

but it forces me to try every possibility when checking for an existing `hand` before `INSERT`, and it's a request which would take hours to write with 8 `card`s in one `hand`.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's best to put a little bit of extra logic in storing the hands.

If you sort the cards first before you insert them. For example if you sort them from low to high there won't be hand(2, 1, 3) in the database, but only a hand(1, 2, 3). That makes the search easier, or, if you put a unique constraint on it, you can just try to insert a new hand and grab the constraint error that it will throw if the hand exists.

Comment: Noob, please read the complete answer before commenting. The unique constraint is only a side note. The point is that you should sort the cards in the hand before storing them. I've modified the text slight in case it was unclear.

Comment: I understand it now :) Sorry  this make more sense. Thanks for the extra explanation

Answer (score -1):

Do you need the separate id column as Primary Key? If not then you can use these card columns as the primary key like 
`ALTER TABLE hand ADD PRIMARY KEY (card_1,card_2,...card_n)`
 which would automatically discard duplicate values.

Comment: Same as a unique constraint or a unique index would do, but it doesn't solve the issue mentioned in the question. You can still insert 2,1,3 and 1,2,3, which should be treated as the same.

Answer (score -1):

You have a one to many relationship between hand and card. You should represent this using a composite primary key and a single card column.

```
CREATE TABLE hand(
id INT,
card INT,
FOREIGN KEY card REFERENCES card(id),
PRIMARY KEY (id,card)
);
```

If hand 101 includes cards 1,2,3 then you represent this with

```
INSERT INTO hand(101,1);
INSERT INTO hand(101,2);
INSERT INTO hand(101,3);
```

Comment: That's an opinion and it depends on how normalized you want your database. For usability and performance you may want to denormalize, especially when you have a database for a specific game that allows a limited number of cards. That aside, your answer may be a useful remark, but it doesn't answer the question in any way.